# What does ApplicationPoolIdentity map to?

Tags: authentication, iis-7.5

When I use ApplicationPoolIdentity on a web site deployed on one box (Win Server 2008 R2) and try to access SQL Server I get:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

but the same configuration on the different box (Win7) gives me:

> Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINE$'.

Both `applicationHost.config` files have:

```
<anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR" />
```

**Question**: where is the difference in configuration? more specifically, what do I need to tweak to have process (web site) authenticate with 'DOMAIN\MACHINE$'?

Context: IIS7 (Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2)

Comment: I know this is old, but hopefully you're still at it.  I found a similar discussion here, but still no answer: http://forums.iis.net/t/1181039.aspx/2/10.  As per timamm's link, they should both be coming through as DOMAIN\MACHINE$.  I am seeing the same problem (with WCF instead of SQL, but same issue).  Can you confirm that these are both domain computers in your case as well?

Answer (score 2):

For information about the IIS ApplicationPoolIdentity and how to configure it, see the IIS.net article [Application Pool Identities](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/).

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching, I came across this Microsoft hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545850.  It seems to solve this problem for me.  I'd have to give credit to several other StackExchange questions:

[IIS application using application pool identity loses primary token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686186/iis-application-using-application-pool-identity-loses-primary-token)
http://serverfault.com/questions/217547/applicationpoolidentity-iis-7-5-to-sql-server-2008-r2-not-working

Comment: i am having same issue, but this hotfix did not fix it for me. please let me know if you have any update.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using integrated security. One box is on the domain and the other isn't. You either need to create SQL logins for those accounts - or a simpler approach is to use SQL authentication. What is your connection string?